# Can't filter data on users select option and render it onclick

Tags: reactjs, api, filter, material-ui

I am making a form web application in react.js with select options(using material UI) and an onclick button. The problem is that I don't know how to filter the data from my local API so that when the user chooses an option on the UI they will then have that specific data from the API rendered when they press submit.

Currently, I have mapped all the data to the submit button:

[image]

Here is the data from the API:

[image]

If for example the user just selects Entry Point and clicks submit then I just want all of the data for Entry Point to be shown.

This is how I am rendering the data in react:

```
const initialData = ({
  first: "",
  second: "",
  third: "",
  fourth: ""
});

const Form = () =>{
  const [Data, updateData] = React.useState(initialData);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateData({
      ...Data,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
    
  const handleAutocompletefirstChange = (e, value) => {
    updateData({
      ...Data,
      first: value,
    });
  };

  const handleAutocompletesecondChange = (e, value) => {
    updateData({
      ...Data,
      second: value
    });
  };

  const handleAutocompletethirdChange = (e, value) => {
    updateData({
      ...Data,
      third: value
    });
  };

  const handleAutocompletefourthChange = (e, value) => {
    updateData({
      ...Data,
      fourth: value
    });
  };

  const options = ['Entry Point', 'Exit Point', 'MTOW (TONNES)', '5 to 40', 'More than 40 and upto 120', 'More than 120 and upto 250', 'More than 250 and upto 350', 'More than 350 and upto 450', 'More than 450']

  const fetchData = async (e) => {
    setSpinner(true);
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/getdata_withQuery');
    console.log(res);

    const data = await res.json();
    setUsers(data);

    console.log(Data);
    const newData = await fetch('/api', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type' : 'application/json',
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: Data.initialData
      })
    })

    .then(res => res.json(setSpinner(false)));
    
    console.log(newData);

  }

  return (

    <div className='container'>
        <Content>

          <div className='features'>
            <div className='buttons'>
              <h1>Fill in Details</h1>

              <form>

                <div className='ComboBox'>
                  <div style={{marginLeft:'0%', marginTop: '0px'}}>
                    <Autocomplete
                    name='initialData'
                    onChange={(event, value) => handleAutocompletefirstChange(event, value)}
                    options={options}
                    style={{ width: 300 }}
                    renderInput={(params) =>
                      <TextField {...params} label="select" variant="outlined" name="first" onChange={handleChange} />}
                  />
                </div>
                <br/>

                <div style={{marginLeft:'0%', marginTop: '0px'}}>
                    <Autocomplete
                    name='initialData'
                    onChange={(event, value) => handleAutocompletesecondChange(event, value)}
                    options={options}
                    style={{ width: 300 }}
                    renderInput={(params) =>
                      <TextField {...params} label="select" variant="outlined" name="second" onChange={handleChange}/>}
                  />
                </div>
                <br/>

                <div style={{marginLeft:'0%', marginTop: '0px'}}>
                    <Autocomplete
                    name='initialData'
                    onChange={(event, value) => handleAutocompletethirdChange(event, value)}
                    options={options}
                    style={{ width: 300 }}
                    renderInput={(params) =>
                      <TextField {...params} label="select" variant="outlined" name="third" onChange={handleChange}/>}
                  />
                  
                </div>            
                <br/>
                <div style={{marginLeft:'0%', marginTop: '0px'}}>
                    <Autocomplete
                    name='initialData'
                    onChange={(event, value) => handleAutocompletefourthChange(event, value)}
                    options={options}
                    style={{ width: 300 }}
                    renderInput={(params) =>
                      <TextField {...params} label="select" variant="outlined" name="fourth" onChange={handleChange}/>}
                  />
                  
                </div>            
                <br/>

                </div>

                <div className='btn'>

                  <Button type="submit" variant="primary" onClick={(e) => fetchData(e)}>Submit</Button>{' '}
                  <Button type='clear' variant="danger">Clear</Button>{' '}

                </div>

            </form>

            <div className='data'>

            {users.map((item) => (
          <div className='map_Data'> 
            <ol key={item.ENTRY_POINT1}>
              Entry_Point: { item.ENTRY_POINT1 }
              <br />
              Exit_Point: { item.EXIT_POINT1 }
              <br />
              Route_Point: { item.RoutePoint }
              <br />
              Distance_Nm: { item.DistanceNm }
              <br />
              MTOW (TONNES): { item.Distance_km }
              <br />
              fourty: {item.fourty}
              <br/>
              onehundredtwenty: {item.onehundredtwenty}
              <br/>
              twohundredfifty: {item.twohundredfifty}
              <br/>
              threehundredfifty: {item.threehundredfifty}
              <br/>
              fourhundredfifty: {item.fourhundredfifty}
              <br/>
              morefourhundredfifty: {item.morefourhundredfifty}
          </ol>
      </div>
      
        ))}
        </div>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
  )
}
```

In my Node API I made this query to pull the data from my MSSQL database:

```
async function getdata_withQuery() {
    try {
      let pool = await sql.connect(config);
      
      let res = await pool.request().query("select [ENTRY_POINT1], [EXIT_POINT1], [RoutePoint], [DistanceNm], ROUND([Distance_km],0) AS [Distance_km], ROUND([Distance_km] * 0.44, 0) AS [fourty], ROUND([Distance_km] * 0.58, 0) AS [onehundredtwenty], ROUND([Distance_km] * 0.88, 0) AS [twohundredfifty], ROUND([Distance_km] * 1, 0) AS [threehundredfifty], ROUND([Distance_km] * 1.14, 0) AS [fourhundredfifty], ROUND([Distance_km] * 1.30, 0) AS [morefourhundredfifty] from [dbo].['Data File$']");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

      return res.recordsets;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(" mathus-error :" + error);
    }
  }
```

For more information here is the repo for my form web-app (src/components/ComboBox.js):
https://github.com/N00rAhmed/Avtag-Form/tree/working-branch

Also here is my Node.js Api: https://github.com/N00rAhmed/flytag-api

I have tried using the filter method in react.js and I was able to make a search filter using a text field, but not using select options because I kept on coming across errors which i didn't understand. I also tried doing an onclick handler on the select option but I quickly realised that wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you attach the data list with your question so someone can help you to create a query to fetch those records?

Comment: here u go I've attached it now

Comment: It's better to provide a workable codesandbox link to show the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

you just get the data once, then give the array to jsx based on your search

this is a function that returns an array based on the given array and the proprety that you want to filter with

```
export const findWithProp = (array, prop) => {
var arrayToReturn =[];
if (prop=== "ALL") {return array;}
else {
array.forEach((element) => {
if (element[prop]){arrayToReturn.push(element);}
});
}
return arrayToReturn;};
```

so in your useEffect each time the value of the filter change let's call it "newValue"

```
const[newValue,setNewValue] = useState("");
```

you can update the arrayToShow and give it to jsx

```
const[arrayToShow,setArrayToShow] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
setArrayToShow(findWithProp (users,newValue))
},[newValue])
```

in your jsx :

```
 {
    arrayToShow.map(element=>{
      return(
      // your logic
      )
 }
```